# Ubuntu sometimes get stuck after waking up from suspension

Tags: boot, nvidia, suspend, 22.10, 23.04

Sometimes waking up after suspending with random durations (it can be minutes, hours) the screen just shows an underscore `_`, pressing `CTRL + ALT + F1 -> F7` just make the underscore disappear and nothing can be done after that other than holding the power button until it shutdown.
this issue has been happening for me for a long time and tried many solutions with no results
happend on `22.04`, `22.10` and `23.04` (the current release I'm using)

I'll upload in logs files that may be needed

##### My setup:

Lenovo Legion 5i

- CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-10750H
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile
- OS: Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64
- Kernel: 6.2.0-76060200-generic

##### from the solutions I've tried:

- setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
- downgrading Nvidia driver
- changed the DE from gnome to KDE

it's starting to get really annoying and I thinking about changing the distro (I'm thinking manjaro, probably because this issue will also happen on Mint or Pop!_OS)
so any help is really appreciated :(